# Problems with adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, $T \in  B(X, Y)$ is bounded linear operator.

> Def: $T$ is topologically injective iff it is homeomorphism onto image.

(a) Is it true that if $T$ is surjective, then $T^*$ is topologically injective? Is the converse true?

(b) Is it true that if $ImT$ is closed in $Y$, then $Im T^*$ is closed in $X^*$? Is the converse true?

For Banach spaces this is all true.

(c) Construct a condition on $T$ that is necessary and sufficient for $T^*$ to be topologically injective.

---

My attempts:

a) The first is not true.

$$ T: l_1 \rightarrow Im(l_1) \subset c_0$$ then
$$ T^* : l_1 \rightarrow l_{\infty} $$
because $Im(l_1)$ with sup-norm is dense in $c_0$ but T* is not homeomorphism.

Converse is not true. Let $X$ - Banach space and $X_0$ is dense subspace and $T = id$. 
$$ T: X_0 \rightarrow X $$
$$ T^*: X^* \rightarrow X^* $$ and $T^*$ is topological isomorphism, but $T$ is not surjection.

b) Converse is not true again because we can choose dense subspace.

I think that there is no implication from the closed $ImT$ to closed $Im T^*$ (I don't know)

c) I know that is necessary $Im T$ is dense in $Y$. Then $T$ is injective, but $T^*$ must be open, then $T$ is isomorhism (bounded but not open (topological)). I think $T$ is isomorhism iff $T^*$ is topological injective.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your guess for c) is false: let $T:l^{2} \to l^{2}$ be the map which sends $\{x_n\}$ to $\{x_2,x_3,..\}$. Then $T^{*}$ sends $\{x_n\}$ to $\{0,x_1x_2,,..\}$. $T^{*}$ is an isometry onto its range so it is topologically injective. But $T$ is not injective, hence not an isomorphism.

Comment: oo exactly, thank you! Then I think, that $T$ must be open, I was wrong when I said that $T^*$ must be open

Comment: so, i can prove that $T^*$ is topologically injective iff $ImT$ is dense in $Y$ and $T^{-1} \left( B_1 \left(0, ImT\right) \right) \leq C$ where is $C > 0$.